# Mongo Update value, inside an array inside an array for aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this kind of document:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "bMeta" : [
                "c33b9ce5ca46075336134a8092bebbbf"
        ],
        "ip" : [
                "a17bdc3ee98c002570b032dfe67f9680"
        ],
        "history" : [
                {
                        "type" : "pType",
                        "name" : "home",
                        "score" : 0,
                        "seen" : [
                                {
                                        "year" : 2014,
                                        "week" : 40,
                                        "score" : 0
                                },
                                {
                                        "year" : 2013,
                                        "week" : 51,
                                        "score" : 0
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

I'd like to update ($inc) the 'score' values for `history.$.score` and `history.$.seen.$.score` where `seen.year` = 2014.

Of course, I can't use more than one `$` so it's not working like that. It's just to show what I need to do.

How would you update it? Knowing that the main goal is to be able to aggregate value with somethink like:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        '$match':
        {
            '_id' : 1
        }
    },
    { '$unwind': '$history' },
    {
        '$match':
        {
            'history.type' : 'pType',
            'history.name' : 'home'
        }
    },
    { '$unwind': '$history.seen' },
    { '$match': { 'history.seen.year' : 2014 } },
    { '$match': { 'history.seen.week' : { $gte: 27 } } },
    { '$group': { _id: '$history.name', total_recent_score: { "$sum": "$history.seen.score" } } },
    { '$sort': { total_recent_score: -1 } },
    { '$limit': 5 }
]).pretty();
```

Do you think of a better document structure to achieve that?

Comment: Can we clarify what you are really asking? Is it "how to 'represent' and incremented value during aggregation?" Or are your actually asking how to actually "increment" the value?

Comment: Ah sorry, it is "how to increment the value". The aggregate is ok (as soon as I can increment my values ;))

Comment: For the nested array, you need to retrieve the document, find the indexes of the element you want to update index in the two arrays, and then use an update clause like `{ "$inc" : { "history.0.seen.0.score" } }`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm currently doing... But it's so complicated, I wanted to have another solution... :(